# Why does Elixir's group_by use a reverse function in the implementation?

Tags: elixir

Here is Elixir's [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) implementation from [Github](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1111):

```elixir
def group_by(enumerable, key_fun, value_fun \\ fn x -> x end)

def group_by(enumerable, key_fun, value_fun) when is_function(key_fun) do
  reduce(reverse(enumerable), %{}, fn entry, acc ->
    key = key_fun.(entry)
    value = value_fun.(entry)

    case acc do
      %{^key => existing} -> Map.put(acc, key, [value | existing])
      %{} -> Map.put(acc, key, [value])
    end
  end)
end
```

Why is the `reverse/1` function applied to the `enumerable`?

Comment: This typically is necessary when a function does head to tail list processing and outputs a list on-the-fly which by its nature has the head now at the tail. reverse undoes that backwards order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to preserve the ordering of the grouped items.

Here is an example using the standard `group_by`:

```elixir
Enum.group_by(["aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc"], &String.first/1)
# %{"a" => ["aa", "ab", "ac"], "b" => ["ba", "bb", "bc"]}
```

If we remove the `reverse` command in a custom implementation:

```elixir
Example.no_reverse_group_by(["aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc"], &String.first/1)
# %{"a" => ["ac", "ab", "aa"], "b" => ["bc", "bb", "ba"]}
```

You can see the internal ordering of the grouped elements `"ac", "ab", "aa"` is the reverse of the original order `"aa", "ab", "ac"`.

The reason is because [`Map.put(acc, key, [value | existing])`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1119)  builds up the groups by adding each `value` element to the front of the `existing` list of elements as they are encountered. This builds up groups with the items in the reverse order compared to the original enumerable.

Prepending to a list is fast, but adding to the end of a list requires traversing the whole list. So to enable the algorithm to use the efficient `[value | existing]` prepend operation, *and* to ensure the order of items in the groups is the same as the original enumerable, it's necessary to first reverse the enumerable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I completely understand it !